# JSON manifest file what am i doing wrong?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

```
{
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "name": "Clock",
  "version": "1",

  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A Plain Analog Clock",
  "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "128": "icon_128.png",  
    },
  },

  "author": Anonymous,
  "automation": Clock,
  "background": {
    "page": "Clock.html"
    "persistent": false
  },
  "background_page": Clock.html,
  },
}
```

What am i doing wrong with this code? I have no clue i am new to JSON. I am trying to build an extension within google chrome.

Comment: Since JSON is a *data* format, there's not much that can be said about yours, except that it's not valid (unquoted strings, superfluous commas). If you're having issues *using* it, then you'll have to tell us *what* you're doing with it.

Comment: I am trying to make a google extension/app on my chromebook. I found this and I am trying to open my Clock.html code through this manifest json file. Here is the basic structure of the code for a manifest file. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

Comment: You should probably make sure your JSON is valid, *and* that it follows that specification. Two separate tasks, probably the easiest to do in that order.

Comment: Ok I am not sure how to do that I am new to JSON I got my base code from the link in my previous comment

Comment: Surely you know how to use a search engine to find enough information about JSON? If not here's a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and http://json.org/

Comment: Yes. By fixing the invalid parts. What are you *really* asking?

Comment: I am trying to make this code work for a google chrome extension. It is not valid can you edit my code and make it valid?

Comment: I could, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. You'll have to do it yourself. It's quite easy, especially since I've told you it's about unquoted strings and superfluous commas.

Comment: Ok ill figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  // Required
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "Clock.html"
    }
  },
    "background": {
      // Optional
      "page": "Clock.html",
      "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Clock",
  "version": "1222",

  // Recommended
  "description": "A clock",
  "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"}
}
```

This is the code that runs the script correctly